# Error when trying to install vcfR in Rstudio

Tags: r, linux, install.packages

I'm having trouble installing the vcfR package in R studio.
I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS in Rstudio and my R version 3.6.3
When I try to install using:

```
install.packages('vcfR')
```

I get a non-zero exit status

```
Installing package into ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/vcfR_1.11.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1453180 bytes (1.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.4 MB

* installing *source* package ‘vcfR’ ...
** package ‘vcfR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
./configure: 4: ./configure: checkbashisms: not found
Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘vcfR’
* removing ‘/home/username/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/vcfR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vcfR’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here or what to try to fix it.

Comment: Do you get an option to install from source?

Comment: @akrun When I try to install the tarball directly using `install.packages('~/Downloads/vcfR_1.11.0.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')` I get the same error `Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/home/dylanjameswallis/Downloads/vcfR_1.11.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: I was able to install on R 4.0 on mac without using the source.  So, may be it is a difference in versions

Comment: @akrun Binary install != source install.

Comment: @Nasally It is a simple bug in the package which (currently) calls `checkbashism` (which you didn't have) unconditionally, which is a bad idea.

Comment: I meant that there is an option and the OP can either specify Yes or No or Cancel

Comment: How does buy him lunch on Ubuntu where the default is still source install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on github, so apparently it is a general issue:

https://github.com/r-hub/rhub-linux-builders/issues/46

I'm also running Ubuntu 18.04.04, and got the same error message as you. I installed the `devscripts` package through the terminal using the following code:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install devscripts
```

I was then able to successfully install vcfR in RStudio.

Comment: That makes no direct sense to me--R maintainer for Debian (and indirectly Ubuntu here).  `checkbashism` is use by R _when checking_ not when installing.

Comment: It is a bug in the package. It's `configure` call `checkbashism`.

Comment: Interesting, I'm really glad you looked into this. I have no background in CS (academic who uses R for stats, mainly), so I was just figuring out a way to install the package. Hopefully the package maintainer(s) fix this soon.

Comment: Degrees don't matter that much.  Do what you need to do to follow your hunches, learn what you need along the way.  My major wasn't CS either, but hey these days I sometimes teach about programming to stats students too.

Answer (score 3):

This would appear to be due to a simple bug in the package `vcfR`. In the most recent version [its `configure` script](https://github.com/cran/vcfR/blob/master/configure) consists of

```
#!/bin/sh

#
checkbashisms --force

# EOF.
```

which makes little to no sense. CRAN never noticed because they now have the script `checkbashishm` (from Debian's `devscript` package) installed.  Someone should tell the maintainer of `vcfR` to correct this. I'll send him a mail. At a minimum it should change to

```
if [ -f /usr/bin/checkbashisms ]; then
    checkbashisms --force
fi
```